# Drawing a barplot for a range of values containing positive and negative numbers

Tags: r

I wish to draw a barplot for the values ranging between -0.5 to 0.5, and am using the code typed below:

```
barplot(c(-0.08,0.02,-0.06,-0.07,-0.07,0.46), names.arg=c('a','b','c','d','e','f'),ylim=c(-0.5,0.5), col="dodgerblue4", xpd = FALSE,axes=TRUE,cex.names=1,
axis.lty=1, ylab="",space=2,las = 2,tck=-0.02,cex.axis=0.6,mgp=c(1, .3, 0))

box()
```

However I also want to add some base-line running horizontally at `y=0.0` to avoid the bars hanging loosely inside the box. Can I do this inside barplot function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for

```
abline(h=0)
```